# C# Add member to nested class of inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, inner-classes

Is this possible to do something like this?:

```
class A
{
    public class B  {
        public static int x = 0;
    }
}

class subA : A
{
    public class B {
        public static int y = 1;
    }
}


// usage:

int n = subA.B.x + subA.B.y;
```

Note that `subA.B` should has same name as 'A.B' and inherites `A.B`'s members with some extra members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# nested classes have no relationship with enclosing class other than accessibility/visiblity (e.g. you can make nested class private so it's only available to the enclosing class).
If you need behavior as you described in the question you need to explicitly mark class B as derived from A.B like this:

```
    class subA : A
    {
        public class B : A.B
        {
            public static int y = 1;
        }
    }
```